# How can I prevent an Android-App from sending background data after closing?

Tags: android, connectivity

I have an Android app that should stay closed if it lose focus. But if the app is closed it still sends background data. How can I prevent the app from sending it or find out which async threads are still active?

Comment: put the Logs in all asynctask and services

Comment: I have active logs for all connections. But if I close the app, I don't get logs in Eclipse any more

Answer (score 2):

try this:-

Suppose you have one AsyncTask like:-

```
class BackgroundFetching extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
    {

    }
```

make its object like

```
private BackgroundFetching mFetching ;
```

now when app is closing, cancel this AsyncTask like:-

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        if(null != mFetching && mFetching.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
        {
            mFetching.cancel(true);
            mFetching = null;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have too many connections, but I'll see what I can do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Detect if the application goes to backgound described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836843/android-detecting-if-an-application-entered-the-background)

Than send / set a flag to your classes to stop they activity of sending data.

Comment: I do it this way:
onUserLeaveHint():
activity.finish();
  
  int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
  android.os.Process.killProcess(pid); Should I separately close all other activities?

Comment: not enough to kill the process programamtically :) some services aren't killed. kill they logic :)

Comment: So I have to log all started services and kill them on app stop?

Comment: @iMx I would do like this: step 1 detect the app when enters in background. Step2. Set a boolean flag to all of your running async tasks (need to keep reference of they ofc. Step 3: in the async task if the flag is set, than stop the task, do not run anymore. Nothing to do with logcat or process kill

Comment: for what should stay the boolean flags?

Comment: @iMx while(canRun){processAChunkOfData(data);} something like that

Answer (score 0):

Kill the application when it lose focus, in other term onPause

```
@Override
protected void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}//End of onPause method
```